# How create constructor with Set field and parametrs TreeSet

Tags: java, constructor, treeset

```
public class Schedule {

    private Set<Seance> schedule;

    public Schedule(){}

    public Schedule(??) {
        super();
        // ??
    }
}
```

I need some this: `private Set<> schedule = new TreeSet<>();` but i need do this in constructor, because i want use Schedule object by sort object Seance/// and this object Schedule I want add to MAP... help please. And sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this !!

```
public Schedule(){
schedule = new TreeSet<Seance>();
}

public Schedule(Set<Seance> schedule) {
    super();
   this.schedule = schedule;
}
```

Comment: Yes its cool but i have condition: in field i need Set<Seanse>, and in constructor i need new TreeSet<Seance>();

Comment: anything will be fine :) 

`public Schedule(TreeSet<Seance> schedule1) {
    super();
   this.schedule = schedule1;
}`

Comment: You can add whatever you want :) After all no one is a born genius and everyone learns by trial and error :) Please mark this answer as helpful if it was :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `TreeSet` object to `Schedule` constructor. And also as you need to sorted Seance you need to use [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). You also need to implement `Comparable`in Seance class or provided `Comparator` in order to sort.

```
public class Schedule {
    private SortedSet<Seance> sortedSet;
    public Schedule(SortedSet<Seance> sortedSet) { 
          this.sortedSet = sortedSet;
    }
}
```